# How to configure USB Pedals with NixOS

Tags: linux, udev, nixos, usb-device

I have a set of USB Pedals that I wish (need!) to configure with NixOS, because frankly my hands are killing me.

The pedals are identified in lsusb:

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 413d:2107
```

And evtest shows the following default key assignments:

```
sudo evtest /dev/input/event6
...
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0x413d product 0x2107 version 0x111
Input device name: "HID 413d:2107 Keyboard"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_Key)
    Event code 1 (KEY_ESC)
...
    Event code 240 (KEY_UNKNOWN)
  Event type 4 (EV_MSC)
    Event code 3 (MSC SCAN)
...
Event: time 1593452123.539558, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 70004
Event: time 1593452123.539558, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 30 (KEY_A), value 1
Event: time 1593452123.539558, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
...
```

So following [techtrickery.com](http://techtrickery.com/pedals.html) and [yulistic.gitlab.io](https://yulistic.gitlab.io/2017/12/linux-keymapping-with-udev-hwdb/), with the relevant [NixOS Option](https://nixos.org/nixos/options.html#services.udev.extrahwdb), I have added lines to my extraHwdb rules:

```
services.udev.extraHwdb = ''
  evdev:input:b*v413Dp2107e*-*
    KEYBOARD_KEY_70004=f13
'';
```

I have tried some variations on the device line, notably `keyboard:usb:v413Dp2107*` and `evdev:input:b*v413Dp2107e*`.

Having added this to my configuration.nix, rebuilt (and switched!), and... nothing.  The pedal continues to produce an 'a' key.

I am confident that the change is being picked up (if I deliberately remove a ';' in the file, it won't build).  But testing with udevadm:

```
sudo udevadm info /dev/input/event6

P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:413D:2107.0004/input/input25/event6
N: input/event6
L: 0
S: input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2:1.0-event-kbd
S: input/by-id/usb-413d_2107-event-kbd
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:413D:2107.0004/input/input25/event6
E: DEVNAME=/dev/input/event6
E: MAJOR=13
E: MINOR=70
E: SUBSYSTEM=input
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=1296521621
E: PATH=/nix/store/k3hi6q6y10zrrgli0xa54zbvzs6pwdl1-udev-path/bin:/nix/store/k3hi6q6y10zrrgli0xa54zbvzs6pwdl1-udev-path/sbin
E: ID_INPUT=1
E: ID_INPUT_KEY=1
E: ID_INPUT_KEYBOARD=1
E: ID_VENDOR=413d
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=413d
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=413d
E: ID_MODEL=2107
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=2107
E: ID_MODEL_ID=2107
E: ID_REVISION=0000
E: ID_SERIAL=413d_2107
E: ID_TYPE=hid
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030101:030102:
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=usbhid
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2:1.0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_2_1_0
E: LIBINPUT_DEVICE_GROUP=3/413d/2107:usb-0000:00:14.0-2
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2:1.0-event-kbd /dev/input/by-id/usb-413d_2107-event-kbd
E: TAGS=:power-switch:
```

There is no evidence there of the configuration as requested.  So presumably I'm doing something daft, but no matter how I stare, I cannot see it.

I'm a suspicious of the fact that the keyboard code (70004) is outside of the range reported by evtest in the header [0..240]; but I don't know if that is relevant.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [Footswitch](https://github.com/rgerganov/footswitch), it supports your model and allows you to program the events.

> Command line utlities for programming PCsensor and Scythe foot switches. There is support for both single pedal devices and three pedal devices.

```
footswitch [-123] [-r] [-s <string>] [-S <raw_string>] [-ak <key>] [-m <modifier>] [-b <button>] [-xyw <XYW>]
   -r          - read all pedals
   -1          - program the first pedal
   -2          - program the second pedal (default)
   -3          - program the third pedal
   -s string   - append the specified string
   -S rstring  - append the specified raw string (hex numbers delimited with spaces)
   -a key      - append the specified key
   -k key      - write the specified key
   -m modifier - ctrl|shift|alt|win
   -b button   - mouse_left|mouse_middle|mouse_right
   -x X        - move the mouse cursor horizontally by X pixels
   -y Y        - move the mouse cursor vertically by Y pixels
   -w W        - move the mouse wheel by W
```

Comment: Wow, thank you @eduardo (and, of course, Radoslav) - that is exactly what I needed.